# How to ActiveSync Windows Mobile 6 to windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-mobile-6.5, activesync, windows-mobile-5.0, windows-mobile-6.1

I have some devices with Windows CE 5, CE 6, Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5. 
Synchronizing with ActiveSycn 4.5 on XP and Windows 7 I have no problems.

Now I'm facing the new Windows 8 and I cannot connect. Does anyone know how to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! First I connected the device, windows 8 detected it, but it could not install it.
Then I executed Windows update on Windows 8, there were like 20 updates pending. This installed Compact framework 2 and 3.5 among other packages. Reboot, and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Download
http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/3/0432540e-2d1a-415d-9c9d-a9963e43503e/drvupdate-amd64.exe  for win8 64bit and reconnect your device.
There are few errors during installation - just ignore it.